# I added a wrong variable to git config. How do I remove it?

Tags: git, github, gitlab-ci, config

```
git config --list
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.email=******
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
user.email==
```

The last variable "user.email==" is creating issue, how do I remove it ?

Comment: Try `git config --list --show-origin` to identify which configuration file contains the problem record.

Answer (score 2):

Use `--unset` for this. ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---unset))

```
git config [--global|--local] --unset user.email
```

As suggested by Richard in his comment, `--show-origin` will tell you whether to use `--local` or `--global` (global config is in `<your user folder>/<your user name>/.gitconfig`, local config in `.git/config`)

Comment: Based on the output above, it's in the `--local` settings, so `--local --unset user.email` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing it via cli

```
git config --unset user.email
git config --global --unset user.email
git config --system --unset user.email
```

Or, to purge both of them

```
git config --unset-all user.email
```

Comment: The only new thing this answer brings is `--unset-all` which is clearly not what OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if this is a global setting, then you normally have a file called `.gitconfig` within your users home directory. Or you have an issue with your project settings, than you can find it within your project in `.git/config`.

You can edit those files with any kind of text editor and adapt/remove configuration in there.

Comment: Using an editor directly on the config file in question is my own preferred method. There are two caveats: you need to know which file to edit (or use `git config --local --edit` for instance, to let Git find the file and run your chosen editor) and you must choose an editor that won't wreck the file (some editors like to save things as Rich Text or UTF-16-LE or something else useless here).